# SharePoint hosted app submit multiple items to list

Tags: javascript, app, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am developing a SharePoint 2013 hosted app and I currently have a 'repeating' table that is being cloned each time a button is clicked.

I currently have three tables which all submit to separate lists only two of these tables however are being cloned to allow multiple items to be submitted. I have managed to submit the first entry in both tables to the required lists however when cloning (repeating) the table this will not submit the cloned rows of inputs.

I have an example fiddle here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adam13hylo/xobwb481/36/)

I am developing this app in Visual Studio 2013 and I currently have JavaScript to submit the inputs to the list:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, weburl);

    var web = appCtxSite.get_web();
    var List = web.get_lists().getByTitle('My List');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    ListItem = List.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    ListItem.set_item('Title', $('#DateInput').val());
    ListItem.set_item('UserID', $('#UserId').val());
    ListItem.set_item('Username', $('#currentUsername').val());

    ListItem.update();

    ctx.load(ListItem);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, QuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, QueryFailed));
});
}
```

I am all of my inputs are inside a table the same as what the jsfiddle is.

I have tried putting the table inside of a form however this continued to just refresh the page instead of submitting the data as required.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Are you getting any error in F12?

Comment: No errors at all, as I said it submits the first item in the table to the required lists, however anything that is in a cloned table will not submit.